# \RequirePackage within \if\else\fi

Tags: conditionals, package-writing

Why does the package `iftex` have to be loaded outside of a `\if...\else\fi` structure?

(The same goes for packages `ifpdf`, `ifluatex`, `ifxetex`.)

Consider:

```
\documentclass{myclass}\begin{document}\end{document}
```

### This works:

i.e., when `\RequirePackage{iftex}` is outside of `\ifodt\else\fi`

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/06/01]
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2013/12/15 v0.1 My Class]
\LoadClass{article}
\newif\ifodt\odttrue

\RequirePackage{iftex}
\ifodt
 \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \RequirePackage[T1]  {fontenc}
\else 
 \ifLuaTeX\RequirePackage{fontspec}\fi
 \ifXeTeX \RequirePackage{fontspec}\fi
 \ifPDFTeX \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
           \RequirePackage[T1]  {fontenc}\fi
\fi
```

### But not this:

i.e., when`\RequirePackage{iftex}` is within `\ifodt\else\fi`

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/06/01]
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2013/12/15 v0.1 My Class]
\LoadClass{article}
\newif\ifodt\odttrue

\ifodt
 \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
 \RequirePackage[T1]  {fontenc}
\else
 \RequirePackage{iftex}
 \ifLuaTeX\RequirePackage{fontspec}\fi
 \ifXeTeX \RequirePackage{fontspec}\fi    
 \ifPDFTeX \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
           \RequirePackage[T1]  {fontenc}\fi
\fi
```

### Error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.12      \ifXeTeX
                   \RequirePackage{fontspec}\fi
?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `\else` branch you have

```
\else
 \RequirePackage{iftex}
 \ifLuaTeX\RequirePackage{fontspec}\fi
 \ifXeTeX \RequirePackage{fontspec}\fi
```

Now `\ifXeTeX` is an undefined command which is OK as this is being skipped but the `\fi` is `\fi` so terminates the *outer* `\ifodt` and things go wrong. Never define conditionals within a TeX primitive `\if..` as this always happens:-)

Answer (score 7):

You have to delay the conditionals when (and if) the `iftex` package has been loaded.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1996/06/01]
\ProvidesClass{myclass}[2013/12/15 v0.1 My Class]

\newif\ifodt
\DeclareOption{odt}{\odttrue}
\ProcessOptions\relax

\LoadClass{article}

\ifodt
  \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \RequirePackage[T1]  {fontenc}
  \expandafter\@gobble
\else
  \RequirePackage{iftex}
  \expandafter\@firstofone
\fi
 {\ifLuaTeX
    \RequirePackage{fontspec}
  \fi
  \ifXeTeX
    \RequirePackage{fontspec}
  \fi
  \ifPDFTeX
    \RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \fi}
```

When `\ifodt` is true, the part in braces is gobbled, while if it is false, it's evaluated; since `iftex` has already been loaded, the conditionals will be defined and so matched with the corresponding `\fi`.

There should be a better control, though, because when

```
 \documentclass[odt]{myclass}
```

is found and LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX are used, the packages `inputenc` and `fontenc` would be loaded, which is discouraged.